# usage of "no such thing as"

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/there-s-no-such-thing-person-as)

> I've told you before, sweetie, there's **no such thing as ghosts**!

Which uses the **plural** form of ghosts following the phrase "no such thing as".

[From the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20such%20thing)

> There is **no such thing as a unicorn**.

Which uses the **singular** form of unicorn after the phrase "no such thing as".

I'm trying to make up a sentence with the phrase. Are there some kind of rules about which one I should use for this particular situation?

> there’s no such thing​ **as an easy job**.

> there’s no such thing​ **as easy jobs**.

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=such%20thing%E2%80%8B%20as%20easy%20jobs%2C%20such%20thing%E2%80%8B%20as%20an%20easy&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuch%20thing%20as%20an%20easy%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csuch%20thing%20as%20an%20easy%3B%2Cc0) shows only the singular form has been used in printed books.

[image]

Comment: Cambridge's example is rather an odd one. The speaker could equally well have said "There's no such thing as a ghost", but seems to use the plural in the sense of 'the phenomenon that we call ghosts'. You can't go wrong if you stick to the singular.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. Does "odd" here mean "strange" or "not happening often"? If it is the latter, that use is reasonable as "ghosts" is probably used to refer to some phenomena collectively. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I meant that it was a strange choice of example because 'no such thing as' is not commonly used with a plural noun.

Comment: It doesn't matter what comes after *there's no such thing as*. *There's no such thing as (**circus clowns riding bicycles who refuse to take public transit**).* What follows is a single noun phrase, regardless of the singularly or plurality of its content. To interpret it differently and force some kind of agreement before the noun phrase would be truly strange: ？ *There **are** no such **things** as ghosts.* I've never hear that before, and it seems to violate at least what's idiomatic.